# How to Match Strings from multiple data frame and return indexes with AND and OR options

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the data frame that I want to search on and get back the matching row number.
`'A'` and `'AB'` are completely different things.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['A','B','AC','AD','NAN','XX','BC','SLK','AC','AD','NAN','XU','BB','FG','XZ','XY','AD','NAN','NF','XY','AB','AC','AD','NAN','XY','LK','AC','AC','AD','NAN','KH','BC','GF','BC','AD']).reshape(5,7),columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'])


    a   b   c   d   e   f   g
0   A   B   AC  AD  NAN XX  BC
1   SLK AC  AD  NAN XU  BB  FG
2   XZ  XY  AD  NAN NF  XY  AB
3   AC  AD  NAN XY  LK  AC  AC
4   AD  NAN KH  BC  GF  BC  AD
```

The strings I will be searching for are from this smaller data frame. Where each row has to be searched as AND, to get back matched string row index of data frame df2.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['A','B','C','D','AA','AB','AC','AD','NAN','BB','BC','AD']).reshape(6,2),columns=['a1','b1'])


a1  b1
0   A   B  # present in the first row of df2
1   C   D  # not present in any row of df2
2   AA  AB # not present in any row of df2
3   AC  AD # present in the second row of df2
4   NAN BB # present in the second row of df2
5   BC  AD # present in the fourth row of df2
```

AND part

Desired output `[0,1,3,4]`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


index1 = df.index # Finds the number of row in df
terms=[]
React=[]
for i in range(len(index1)): #for loop to search each row of df dataframe
  terms=df.iloc[i] # Get i row
  terms[i]=terms.values.tolist() # converts to a list
  print(terms[i]) # to check
    # each row
  for term in terms[i]: # to search for each string in the 
    print(term)
    results = pd.DataFrame()
    if results.empty:
      results = df2.isin( [ term ] )
    else:
      results |= df2.isin( [ term ] ) 
  results['count'] = results.sum(axis=1)
  print(results['count'])
  print(results[results['count']==len(terms[i])].index.tolist())
  React=results[results['count']==len(terms[i])].index.tolist()
  React
```

Getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`  on `results = df2.isin( [ term ] )`

For OR it should be easy buy have to exclude AND parts which are already Accounted in the first section

```
React2=df2.isin([X]).any(1).index.tolist()
React2
```

Comment: Raise the desired output of your supposed 'df2'.

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you so much for your comment. I did add the desired output after your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the output you'd expect, but I asked for the index in the AND condition. The resulting list of output contains the df2 indexes on a df row-by-row basis. Does this meet the intent of your question?

```
output = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    tmp = []
    for k in range(len(df2)):
        d = df2.loc[k].isin(df.loc[i,['a1']])
        f = df2.loc[k].isin(df.loc[i,['b1']])
        d = d.tolist()
        f = f.tolist()
        if sum(d) >= 1 and sum(f) >=1:
            tmp.append(k)
    output.append(tmp)

output
[[0], [], [], [0, 1, 3], [1], [0, 4]]
```

Comment: Perfect this is working but i need some time to test with my original data. Please allow me sometimes 12 hr would be enough for me to test this. Thank you so much.